# Facing issue in Salesforce Summary formula report

Tags: reporting

I have created a custom number field in case object .  It is called Overall Minutes  When I run a report, I get the sum of all the minutes at the bottom.  I would like it to be displayed as hours and minutes.  i have tried the below formula but i'm facing issue .

```
ROUND(Case.OverAll_Minutes__c:SUM)/60 & "Hour(s)"
```

> Error: Invalid custom summary formula definition: Incorrect parameter
>   type for operator '&'. Expected Text, received Number

Answer (score 2):

Report builder does not allow to create custom formula fields of type String.

You can up vote this idea in which users are requesting it: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000IySFAA0

I can see two workarounds:

1. Create a formula field in the Case object that reflect the logic you
   want to build and add this new field to the report.
2. Create 3 custom formula fields in the report one for each of info
   you want and use the Column Name to specify if the field is showing
   minutes, hours or days. With this workaround you just need to use
   the formula without try appending any text.

Hopes this helps!

Regards

Comment: There is no Text () function in custom summary formula . Could you help me how to convert over all minutes into days,hours,mintues in reports.

Example : In summarize reports i should show like Ex:5 days,24 hours,6 mintues.

Comment: Unfortunately you can not do this kind of thing in reports custom formula fields. You can up vote this idea in which users a requesting it: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000IySFAA0, I'm going to update the answer to reflect all this stuff so that all can take advantage of it in case the face the same problem.